# How to review a commit that moves large chunks of code around?

Tags: version-control

For refactoring, I'm literally copy-and-pasting to split a file in half.

Conceptually this commit is very simple, but it shows up on source control tools as a big chunk of red (for deletion) and two big chunks of green (for addition). There is no side-by-side view, no indication that the chunks are identical, making it very hard to review.

How to review a commit like this?

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn’t it be obvious at a glance that the big chunks are identical?

What VCS are you using? What are you viewing the diffs with?

Comment: I'm using Phabhricator. How to verify at a glance that 200 lines of code are identical? Yes they will look identical, but doesn't it require running a diff to know if they are truly identical?

Comment: @Heisenberg I’ve never used Phabricator, so I don’t know what its diff view is like. Perhaps something like FileMerge/opendiff on Mac OS X, which does attempt to show moved blocks, is what you want, but that only works well on individual files. There must be a diff viewer that does this for a whole project...